# SQL: How do I list all of customer ID that had their first 2 orders exactly in the sequence of: first order being hat, second order being sunglasses?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am new to SQL and I am trying to figure out the query:
How do I list all of customer ID that had their first 2 orders exactly in the sequence of: first order being hat, second order being sunglasses?

Thanks!

Comment: sample data set and expected out put would help to get prompt answers

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Can you share the table structure and example data?

Answer (score 1):

Well, in BigQuery you can do something like this:

```
select o.customerId
from orders o
group by o.customerId
having array_agg(o.product order by o.order_date asc limit 2) = array['hat', 'sunglasses'];
```

You don't specify what the data looks like, but this should give you the idea of an approach.

Answer (score -1):

you try like this

```
SELECT CustomerID, Product
FROM Customers
WHERE Productin ('Hat', 'sunglasses')
order by Product Asc
```

Comment: I'm not 100% sure of the solution, but you should definitely be selecting from Orders table instead of/as well as Customers